# Lenovo Y560 black screen on normal boot. Boots if I disable AMD Radeon drivers via Safe mode. How to enable display drivers without reboot?

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I have a Lenovo Y560 (Win 7 x64). When I restart my laptop I get to the Windows boot logo and then the screen goes black. I am able to boot into Safe mode but if I then try and restart I get the same thing. The only way to boot into Windows normally is when I disable my AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 graphics drivers via Safe mode by going to Device Manager. This will boot the system without issue. I figured I would do this (disable graphics drivers in safe mode) then enable the Graphics drivers once the laptop boots but when I do Windows tells me that I have to restart Windows for changes to take affect which takes me right back to the problem I'm trying to solve.

Is there a way to Enable my graphics drivers without having to restart the laptop? Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open "Control Panel"
2. Search "Power Options"and then open it.
3. Select "High Performance" then click on "Change Plan Settings"
4. Now, Click on "Change Advance Power Settings
5. Scroll down and find "ATI Graphics Power Settings"
6. Click on "+" button. click on second "+" button.
   now you can see two options 
   (i)  "On Battery Maximize Battery Life"
   (ii) "Plugged in Maximize Performance"
7. Change both "Maximize Performance" to "Maximize Battery Life" 
   8.Click on "OK" Button and Close this Window.
   9.Make sure your "Power Plan" is set on "High Performance"

   Your Problem is solved...

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix on Lenovo forums for an issue that I think is the same as your issue. Here's the link: [Y560 Black Screen After Boot Up](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Y560-Black-Screen-After-Boot-Up/m-p/452723#M74115)

And here's the pertinents:

> I would like you to uninstall the ATI driver via safe mode, then boot
>   into normal and try to cancel off the installation.   if you're able
>   to cancel the ATI driver installation in normal mode, kindly try the
>   following steps.
>
> 1. Go to system properties
> 2. click on "Advance System Properties"
> 3. click on "hardware" then on "Device Installation Settings"
> 4. select radio button "No, let me choose what to do"
> 5. select radio button "Never install driver software from Windows Update"
> 6. click Save Changes.   once the above is done, restart your system. The steps above is to stop the computer from auto-installing, now go
>      to http://support.lenovo.com and do an update of your computer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.